# Customized DevExpress LookupeditSettings

Tags: silverlight, devexpress

I write my customized lookupedit(derived from lookupedit)

I want to use it in lookupeditsettings instead of lookupedit
How can i do this?
(in Silverlight)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you review the [Custom Editors](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument9325) help topic, which describes basic concepts of this task (this article is applicable both for WPF and Silverlight).

Answer (score 0):

You can get help topic [Custom Editors](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument9325) that illustrates how to `inherit` from `DevExpress` editors/settings.

Check the [LookUpEditBase](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/clsDevExpressXpfEditorsLookUpEditBasetopic) class for it's member and properties and then try to implement customization code. For  more help on the topic go through DevExpress Documentation of LookupEdit and this [search result](http://search.devexpress.com/default.aspx?q=custom%20editor%20lookupedit&p=T4%7CP3%7C0&d=762&page=1) on [lookupEdit Customization](http://search.devexpress.com/?q=custom%20editor%20&p=T4%7CP3%7C0&d=762).

*If you looking for further assistance then follow the DevExpress Q&A thread - [using custom lookupedit in lookupeditsettings](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q402541.aspx)*

Hope this help.